# Isolating version upgrade instillation and first time intalation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

I have deployed to version 1.0 to Apple store. And i'm getting ready for Version 1.1

My question is how to display pop up message to the only users who upgrade my app from version 1.0 to 1.1

I do not need to display that message to the users who install version 1.1 first time.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My only idea is that you check, if there are some data in the Documents Folder or settings set. But's that's only possible, if your app save some data there.